# printer prints 2 pages an stops

Tags: printing, hplip

I have a HP laserjet 4650hdn, printer. Recently I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04, and therefore also reinstalled my printer. The printer prints fine still, in quality, but will only print 2 pages then it stops. After that, if I open the paper tray, and close it, again, the printer will put out 2 more pages.

No errors show up either on the printer console, nor in the linux control panel. What should I do to troubleshoot this?